How to Convert Squared L2 Distances to Similarity Scores
When using L2 (Euclidean distance) as the metric type in Milvus, the scores returned are squared L2 distances, which range from [0.0, +∞]. How can I convert these scores to similarity scores in the range [0, 1], where 1 indicates the highest similarity? Please provide an example.
I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be the correct way:
from pymilvus import Collection, connections

# Connect to Milvus
connections.connect("default", host="localhost", port="19530")

collection_name = "example_collection"
collection = Collection(collection_name)

query_vectors = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]]

search_params = {"metric_type": "L2", "params": {"nprobe": 10}}

top_k = 5
results = collection.search(query_vectors, "vector_field", search_params, top_k=top_k)

similarity_scores = []
for result in results:
    similarities = [1 / (1 + score) for score in result.distances]
    similarity_scores.append(similarities)

print(similarity_scores)

